# Solve non-linear recurrence

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, induction

I am trying to solve the following recurrence (i.e. determine $a_n$). I'm not entirely sure how to proceed, I have only encountered linear ones so far. This is not a homework, I'm just doing it for fun.

$$a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{a_n}=2$$

Comment: My answer to [1483830](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483830/recurrence-relationship) provides complete details.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly straightforward to prove by induction that $a_n=\frac{na_1-(n-1)}{(n-1)a_1-(n-2)}$ for $n \geq 1$.

**Edit:** To get the pattern, one can play around with the first few terms, so $a_2=2-\frac{1}{a_1}=\frac{2a_1-1}{a_1}$, then $a_3=2-\frac{1}{a_2}=2-\frac{a_1}{2a_1-1}=\frac{3a_1-2}{2a_1-1}$, then $a_4=2-\frac{1}{a_3}=2-\frac{2a_1-1}{3a_1-2}=\frac{4a_1-3}{3a_1-2}$. After a while, the pattern shows itself, and is then easily proven by induction.

Comment: Good --- but, how would you stumble across that formula to begin with?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good point. I've edited to add in some motivation.